# Packer loops through ports when attempting to establish SSH connection

Tags: ssh, packer

When Packer reaches the  "Waiting for SSH to become available..." step.

My logs show

```
14:07:29 [INFO] Attempting SSH connection...
14:07:29 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
14:07:29 handshaking with SSH
14:07:29 handshake error: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60372->127.0.0.1:3057: read: connection reset by peer
14:07:29 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60372->127.0.0.1:3057: read: connection reset by peer

14:07:36 [INFO] Attempting SSH connection...
14:07:36 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
14:07:36 handshaking with SSH
14:07:36 handshake error: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60376->127.0.0.1:3057: read: connection reset by peer
14:07:36 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60376->127.0.0.1:3057: read: connection reset by peer
```

Note a different port on each attempt.

```
60372
60376
```

Packer is trying a new port, every 7 seconds.

Is there a way to configure the ports before or during the build to avoid this try/fail approach?

Comment: What you're seeing is typical behavior for a TCP client. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: The problem is that the time to find the good port is anywhere between 10 to 60 mins. It makes the builds unpredictable and occasionally timeout. My Jenkins job is 45 mins. When I run the packer manually, it usually takes 5-15 mins.

Comment: "connection reset by peer" usually points to some problem on the ssh server. Are you sure the source port being used by the client is relevant to your problem?

Comment: if I wait long enough, the connection eventually established and the rest is done as expected. How can I troubleshoot ssh server? what should I look for? As a user, I remote into Server using Powershell SSH. Does it affect other outgoing connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with SSH Server or TCP/IP. It is with the way Packer is designed.

When a VM is created, Packer.io will run boot commands. It takes time and time varies on different machines. During that time you will see "Waiting for SSH to become available...". On the background, Packer.io will be attempting to establish an SSH connection. The log is saturated with messages like this

```
Linux
14:07:29 [INFO] Attempting SSH connection...
14:07:29 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
14:07:29 handshaking with SSH
14:07:29 handshake error: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60372->127.0.0.1:3057: read: connection reset by peer
14:07:29 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp    127.0.0.1:60372->127.0.0.1:3057: read: connection reset by peer
```

or

```
Windows
15:54:31 packer.exe: 2017/02/01 15:54:31 [INFO] Attempting SSH connection...
15:54:31 packer.exe: 2017/02/01 15:54:31 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
15:54:31 packer.exe: 2017/02/01 15:54:31 handshaking with SSH
15:54:31 packer.exe: 2017/02/01 15:54:31 handshake error: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:62691->127.0.0.1:4289: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
15:54:31 packer.exe: 2017/02/01 15:54:31 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:62691->127.0.0.1:4289: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

OS will boot and with it SSH server on the guest will become available. At that moment SSH connection from host to guest should establish.

Reproduced and Confirmed on Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 16.04.1 TLs

Answer (score 1):

That is the source port which the ssh connection is made from. It's assigned by the OS with a random available high port.

Comment: it seem to be the other way around, the source port is after > the first port is destination port. SSH is trying random ports when the first one fails.

Comment: No it doesn't seem like that.

Comment: It fails because sshd hasn't started yet.

Comment: You are correct, that's because the guest OS is still being installed and configured. It's SSH agent does not become available until later. Meanwhile, host OS is spamming connections every 7 seconds. The trouble is that I noticed time varies on the same host. Sometimes it takes 5 mins, sometimes 15, when I add Jenkins (with no jobs running in parallel) the time spikes up to 30-40 mins.

Comment: It's very likely that your Jenkins server is 1/3 of the speed of your laptop. Try running Jenkins on the laptop and you will have similar runtimes. Install OS'es is slow 5+ minutes is not uncommon for Linux. Installing Windows is way slower.